# What determines the length of an Integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have been wondering what could be the maximum length of Integer before it gets to Float::INFINITY.

## On my 64 bit (Arch Linux) system:

```
> 1023.**(3355446).bit_length
# => 33549731

> 1023.**(3355446).+(1000000 ** 1000000).+(1000 ** 100).bit_length
# => 33549731
```

In fact:

```
> a = 1023.**(3355446) ; ''
# => ""

> b = 1023.**(3355446).+(1000000 ** 1000000).+(1000 ** 100) ; ''
# => ""

> a.to_s.length == b.to_s.length
# => true
```

## The above takes some time, but this one doesn't

```
a, b, length_of = 1023.**(3355446), 1023.**(3355446).+(1000000 ** 1000000).+(1000 ** 100), lambda { |x| Math.log10(x).to_i.next } ; ''
# => ""

length_of.(a).eql?(length_of.(b))
# => true
```

Thus, if you are running a program, which has an infinite loop and a counter which increases many hundreds or thousands of times a second, and you have to run it 24 * 365, that may cause bugs I think.

So the question is what determines the length of the Integer in Ruby? Does it differ on 32 bit and 64 bit systems?

## Edit:

On my rapsberry pi 3 model B:

```
2.**(31580669).bit_length
# => 31580670

2.**(31580669).next.bit_length
# => 31580670

> l = ->(x) { Math.log10(x).to_i.next }
# => #<Proc:0x00a46df0@(irb):1 (lambda)>

> l === 2.**(31580669)
# => 9506729

> l === 2.**(31580669) + 100 ** 100
# => 9506729
```

So the question on Ruby 2.3 and older would be how big could be a Bignum. From Ruby 2.4+ the question is how big can be an Integer?

Comment: "if you are running a program, which has an infinite loop and a counter which increases many hundreds or thousands of times a second, and you have to run it 24 * 365" - if that code runs for a few billion years, _then_ your descendants might start noticing the slowdown.

Comment: You may wish to read [this article](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/1/9/how-big-is-a-bignum) by Pat Shaughnessy

Comment: "before it gets to Float::INFINITY" - you can't "count to infinity", that's the whole point of the concept. Unless you're Chuck Norris, that is. Then you can.

Comment: But I don't get it why `eval("0x#{?f * 800000000}").to_i.bit_length` returns `3200000000`!! That's huge! Warning: This will use about 2.9 GiB 3 GB of RAM!!

Comment: "But I don't get it why `eval("0x#{?f * 800000000}").to_i.bit_length` returns `3200000000`!!" – Because that number requires 3200000000 bits to represent.

Comment: I mean if 33549731 is the maximum value before Integer gets to Float::INFINITY, how the code `eval("0x#{?f * 800000000}").to_i.bit_length` can return 3200000000?

Comment: Because there are no floats involved when you do that?

Answer (score 2):

> *What could be the maximum length of Integer before it gets to Float::INFINITY.*

Integer operations in Ruby will (almost) never return Infinity. An Integer can be as big as you have memory to hold it.

`Float` is implemented as a classic [double precision-floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) with an upper limit of about 1.7976931348623157e+308 and will return `Float::Infinity` if you go to high.

```
1.7976931348623157e+308.to_f + 10**307
 => Infinity
```

Some languages, like Perl 5, upgrade integers to doubles to get more space to work. So you will get Infinity if you go too high.

```
$ perl -wle 'printf "%f\n", 10**308'
100000000000000001097906362944045541740492309677311846336810682903157585404911491537163328978494688899061249669721172515611590283743140088328307009198146046031271664502933027185697489699588559043338384466165001178426897626212945177628091195786707458122783970171784415105291802893207873272974885715430223118336.000000
$ perl -wle 'printf "%f\n", 10**308 + 10**308'
Inf
```

But Ruby's `Integer`s have no limit but your memory. When Integers get too large they switch to using the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) which supports [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

There are a few operations which can result in Infinity, like power.

```
10**10000000
(irb):5: warning: in a**b, b may be too big
 => Infinity
```

But multiplication has no such limit.

```
a = 10**1000000
...
a *= a
...
a *= a
...
a *= a
...
a.bit_length
 => 26575425
```

> Thus, if you are running a program, which has an infinite loop and a counter which increases many hundreds or thousands of times a second, and you have to run it 24 * 365, that may cause bugs I think.

This is a real world concern for 32 bit integers which becomes [a pressing problem as 2038 approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), but not 64 bit integers. If we incremented a counter a million times a second it would take almost 300,000 years. What I've just described is 64 bit time with microsecond resolution.

But in Ruby you can make a simple counter effectively as large as you want.